# UnboundLocalError initializing a python class

Tags: python, class

I am creating a Python class but it seems I can't get the constructor class to work properly. Here is my class:

```
class IQM_Prep(SBconcat):
    def __init__(self,project_dir):
        self.project_dir=project_dir #path to parent project dir
        self.models_path=self.__get_models_path__() #path to parent models dir
        self.experiments_path=self.__get_experiments_path__()     #path to parent experiemnts dir

    def __get_models_path__(self):
        for i in os.listdir(self.project_dir):
            if i=='models':
                models_path=os.path.join(self.project_dir,i)
        return models_path

    def __get_experiments_path__(self):
        for i in os.listdir(self.project_dir):
            if i == 'experiments':
                experiments_path= os.path.join(self.project_dir,i)
        return experiments
```

When I initialize this class:

```
project_dir='D:\\MPhil\\Model_Building\\Models\\TGFB\\Vilar2006\\SBML_sh_ver\\vilar2006_SBSH_test7\\Python_project'

IQM= Modelling_Tools.IQM_Prep(project_dir)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-49-7c46385755ce>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/MPhil/Python/My_Python_Modules/Modelling_Tools/Modelling_Tools.py', wdir='D:/MPhil/Python/My_Python_Modules/Modelling_Tools')

  File "C:\Anaconda1\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 585, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "D:/MPhil/Python/My_Python_Modules/Modelling_Tools/Modelling_Tools.py", line 1655, in <module>
    import test

  File "test.py", line 19, in <module>
    print parameter_file

  File "Modelling_Tools.py", line 1536, in __init__
    self.models_path=self.__get_models_path__() #path to parent models dir

  File "Modelling_Tools.py", line 1543, in __get_models_path__
    return models_path

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'models_path' referenced before assignment
```

`Modelling_Tools` is the name of my custom module.

Comment: Could you give the full traceback? Also what's with the `__weird_method_names__` - those aren't real magic methods, you shouldn't name them that way.

Comment: To separate methods that'll get used to create class attributes from the others. Is this not convention or am I missing something? And yes, sure.

Comment: If they're private to the class, use a `_single_leading_underscore`. The `__double_leading_and_trailing_underscore__` is for the pre-defined *"magic methods"* like `__init__` and `__str__`.

Comment: For your actual question, what do you think will happen if none of the items in the directory are called "models"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the traceback, it seems that either:

```
def __get_models_path__(self):
    for i in os.listdir(self.project_dir):  # 1. this never loops; or
        if i=='models':  # 2. this never evaluates True
            models_path=os.path.join(self.project_dir,i)  # hence this never happens
    return models_path  # and this causes an error
```

You should review the result of `os.listdir(self.project_dir)` to find out why; either the directory is empty or nothing in it is named `models`. You could initialise e.g. `models_path = None` at the start of the method, but that would just hide the problem until later.

---

**Sidenote**: per my comments, you should check out the [style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), particularly on naming conventions for methods...

Comment: Yes, it was 2. The folder I was after is called `Models` not `models`. Thanks

Comment: @user3059024 if `models` **or** `Models` would be OK, as not all file systems are case sensitive, you could consider `if i.lower() == 'models':`.

Answer (score 0):

`models_path` is initialized only when:

- `self.project_dir` has some files/dirs and
- one of this file/dir has name `models`

If one of this condition is not fullfiled, then `models_path` is not initialized.